# C# Unity3D playing a .wav saved as BLOB in SQLite database

Tags: c#, sqlite, unity-game-engine

I have a database with different words in it, and with the words is a wav file stored in a blob with the pronunciation. I'm stuck trying to get the BLOB to read as a AudioClip for Unity.

So far I have the sound file somewhat resembling my original in the fact that its the same length, but there's a lot of static.

```
private float [] ConvertByteToFloat ( byte [] array )
{
    float[] floatArr = new float [ array.Length / 4 ];
    for ( int i = 0; i < floatArr.Length; i++ )
    {
        if ( !System.BitConverter.IsLittleEndian )
            System.Array.Reverse( array, i * 4, 4 );
        floatArr [ i ] = System.BitConverter.ToSingle( array, i * 4 );
    }
    return floatArr;
}
float[] stream = ConvertByteToFloat((byte[]) reader["Sound"]);
AudioClip clip = AudioClip.Create( ( string ) reader [ "Name" ], stream.Length, 2, 44100, false, false );
clip.SetData( stream, 0 );
```

There was only static earlier when IsLittleEndian was if(true), if not true made it a little more accurate, but still not what it was before.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is how to read AudioClip data from memory? Use [AudioClip.SetData API](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioClip.SetData.html). For example,

```
AudioClip audioClip = AudioClip.Create("Sound", data.Length, 1, 44100, false, false);
audioClip.SetData(data, 0);
```

Or you can use AudioClip AssetBundle from sqlite3 blob data via [AssetBundle.CreateFromMemory](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetBundle.CreateFromMemory.html) if you have Pro license.

Comment: I forgot to copy that line at the end, I do have 
    clip.SetData( stream, 0 );
I went back to it just now and its sounding a little bit smoother, but not without static. I also do not have pro.

Comment: **stream** should be floats ranging from 0.0f to 1.0f. reader["Sound"] is the exactly same as wav file? you should decode wav file into raw floats.

Comment: I saw in one of the comments about PCM is wavs, I'm going to check that and get back here tomorrow.

Comment: Setting the PCM is a delegate, not sure what to do for that.